# Error when creating App Packages

Tags: .net, vb.net, uwp

Does anybody understand what the following paragraph is trying to say?

What do I have to do to get rid of this error so that I can submit my app on Windows Store?

Any solution might help. Thanks!

```
'Libraries imported are as follows:
Imports Windows.Storage
Imports Windows.Web.Http
Imports Windows.UI.Popups
Imports Windows.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Numerics
Imports WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting
```

> **Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:**
>
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification
>   Kit\SupportedAPIs-x64.xml' is denied. at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at
>   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize) at
>   System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials
>   credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy) at
>   System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type
>   ofObjectToReturn) at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData) at
>   System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack,
>   ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl() at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean
>   preserveWhitespace) at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
>   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename) at
>   Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.SupportedApis.SupportedApis.GetNativeAllowList()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.SupportedApis.SupportedApis.ExecuteSharedTests(EnumApplicationType
>   appType, String packageFullName) at
>   Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.SupportedApis.SupportedApis.Test(UapApp
>   uapApp) at
>   Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.TestBase.TestBase.ExecuteTest()
>   [HRESULT 0x80131604] Test operation failed: 'ExecuteTest'.
>
> Impact if not fixed: Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK
>   for Windows Store apps violates the Windows Store certification
>   requirements.
>
> How to fix: Review the error messages to identify the API that is not
>   part of the Windows SDK for Windows Store apps. Please note, apps that
>   are built in a debug configuration or without .NET Native enabled
>   (where applicable) can fail this test as these environments may pull
>   in unsupported APIs. Retest your app in a release configuration, and
>   with .NET Native enabled if applicable. See the link below for more
>   information:  Alternatives to Windows APIs in Windows Store apps.

Comment: Are you running as admin? How is the program being ran? Whatever is running the application does not have access to that directory.

Comment: I am running as admin. First, I created an app package (required for windows store submission). Next, it prompt me to run a series of tests so that it could pass windows store certification. When I completed the test, this is the only segment which failed. I don't know what it means. all i know is that I can't find the error.

Answer (score 5):

had had the same problem. The owner of the file SupportedAPIs-x64.xml had been set to none, so I changed it to the SYSTEM. Also under Permissions there had been a line SYSTEM and other columns for this principal had been empty. There were another principal SYSTEM and its other columns were ok. So I deleted the first SYSTEM principal and everything was OK.
Just open properties of that file and under Security click on Advanced button.
Basically I compared permissions of the file with permissions of the SupportedAPIs-x86.xml.
Try to open the file in notepad, if it works.

Comment: I had left a domain, and the supportedapis-x64,xml had this issue, but also had the old domain account (with a huge serial number for a name) assigned to it. Your answer worked, and I also removed the dead domain account. Now WACK passes.