# Trying to Resolve supported APIs test detected the errors:

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Hi I' getting following Error While Creating App Package Locally.
Error Found:

> The supported APIs test detected the following errors:
>   ◦System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification
>   Kit\SupportedAPIs-x64.xml' is denied. at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at
>   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize) at
>   System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials
>   credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy) at
>   System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type
>   ofObjectToReturn) at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData) at
>   System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack,
>   ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl() at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean
>   preserveWhitespace) at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
>   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename) at
>   Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.SupportedApis.SupportedApis.GetNativeAllowList()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.SupportedApis.SupportedApis.ExecuteSharedTests(EnumApplicationType
>   appType, String packageFullName) at
>   Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.SupportedApis.SupportedApis.Test(UapApp
>   uapApp) at
>   Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.TestBase.TestBase.ExecuteTest()
>   ◦[HRESULT 0x80131604] Test operation failed: 'ExecuteTest'.

.Any Idea On how tO tresOLVE IT.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that this older question is dealing with the same issue:
[Error when creating App Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256071/error-when-creating-app-packages)

(stackoverflow experts, I don't know how to mark the question as a duplicate or something of the sort - maybe I don't even have the permission to do so)